# Method to remotely access HDFS in JAVA that works on old and new versions of Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to remotely access the HDFS with a program written in JAVA.  WebHDFS works well with most recent versions of Hadoop, but which protocol(s) should I choose that will work on the largest number of versions of Hadoop?

If possible, I would like to use a single protocol that will work on all versions of Hadoop as long as it won't run much slower than using different protocols for different versions of Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

LibHDFS is present in older (1.x) and newer (2.x) releases of hadoop. It is pure java and has pretty stable API.

Comment: LibHDFS is for C, not JAVA.  The HDFS protocol does seem to work on the most versions though.